# Get element from xml file in c#

Tags: c#, xml, getelementsbytagname

I have an xml file which contains an element .
i am storing the content of that xml file as string in csv in one of my projects.i am reading the content of that xml from csv and i want the data of the tag  which exists in the content of xml file
I tried like this.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(Convert.ToString(dataRow["XML"]));
var temp = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Mail");
```

but I am not getting the value of Mail into temp.what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetElementsByTagName` returns `XmlNodeList`. [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dc0c9ekk(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
// Display all the book titles.
XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("title");

for (int i=0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
{   
    Console.WriteLine(elemList[i].InnerXml);
}
```

**Linq solution:**

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(dataRow["XML"].ToString());

var mailList = xDoc.Descendants("Mail")
                   .Select(x => new
                    {
                        MailID = x.Element("MailID").Value
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

**UPDATE**:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(Convert.ToString(dataRow["XML"]));
var temp = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Mail");

// loop through all retrieved "Mail" elements 
foreach(XmlElement xElem in temp)
{
     string sMailText = xElem.InnerText;
}
```